# PHP 7.3 update didn't take

Tags: 16.04, server, php, php7

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

I updated to php 7.3. Everything appeared to go correctly. However when I type in php -v I get

> "PHP 7.2.24-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Oct 24 2019
>   18:28:51) ( NTS )"

The same version shows in pipeinfo.
I have rebooted the server.
The php 7.3 module was enabled for Apache. Apache does state that it is enabled. 
I have restarted apache.

When I do a locate on php7.3 I see the various folders and files. Why isn't version 7.3 running?

Comment: Probably you still have PHP 7.2 packages installed. Run `apt list --installed | grep php` to see all installed PHP packages, and remove those you no longer need with `apt remove`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because the php command still links to the old php 7.2 binary.

Locate the path of the php command:

```
which php
```

It may output something like `/usr/bin/php`

Delete this old link:

```
rm /usr/bin/php
```

Create a new link:

```
ln -s path/to/php7.3 /usr/bin/php
```

Try it:

```
php -v
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. There was a small typo. It should be ""ln" and not "ls".

Comment: -1 Do not `rm` files installed by packages when you can just uninstall the package instead.

Comment: So why exactly is it bad to rm the file you're going to overwrite anyway?

Comment: Also, what if you want to keep the packet? For example for compatibility reasons?

Comment: This worked. Not sure why it was downvoted?

Comment: @NealM Because uninstalling is the preferred way to remove a program? And that's what the second comment is about.

Comment: Clearly I am missing something here. I didn't uninstall anything, I upgraded from 7.2 to 7.3. Are you stating that I should have uninstalled 7.2 before upgrading to 7.3? Isn't that what the upgrade script should do? I'm trying to understand what happened and the why behind the "you should use uninstall"

Comment: @DKBose so what if you want to keep both versions?